# groupadd command not found on Mac Monterey ver 12.1

Tags: macos, command-line, group

I am running macOS Monterey version 12.1

uname -a gives:
21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:28:41 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64

**groupadd** command is not found.

It is not preset in */usr/sbin* folder , inspected it as *root*.

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `groupadd` binary is not part of macOS.

To create new groups

- via UI: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac
- via commandline: https://serverfault.com/questions/131942/how-do-i-add-a-group-in-mac-os-x-10-6